# Ошибка времени выполнения: Входная строка имела неверный формат

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

```
const
n = 5;

var
  f: text;
  r: array[1..n] of real;
begin
  assign(f, 'input.txt');
  reset(f);
  var i: integer := 1;
  var min: real := 0;
  while not eof(f) do
  begin
    var a: string := '';
    readln(f, a);
    var b: real := StrToFloat(a);    
    if b > 0
      then     
      r[i] := b;
    write(r[i], ' ');
    inc(i);
    if b < min
      then min := b;    
  end; 
  writeln('мин элемент: ',min);  
end.
```

"Ошибка времени выполнения: Входная строка имела неверный формат."
 в строке "var b: real := StrToFloat(a);", в файле "1,123 -2,334 4,324 0,123 -5,123455 -3,1432 0,234"

Comment: В чем возникли трудности?

Comment: Очевидно строка `1,123 -2,334 4,324 0,123 -5,123455 -3,1432 0,234` не является дробным числом. Какой-то у вас хитрый паскаль `var b: real := StrToFloat(a);`

Comment: @kot-da-vinci, это pascalABC.NET, он позволяет использовать подобные конструкции

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, что же записано у вас во входном файле.

1. Если `"1,123 -2,334 4,324 0,123 -5,123455 -3,1432 0,234"` записано в одну строку, то вы используете не ту функцию, необходимо использовать `function ReadRealFromString(s: string; var from: integer): real` которая  считывает вещественное из строки начиная с позиции from и устанавливает from за считанным значением. И вы должны в цикле считать все числа, пока не придете к концу строки.
2. Если же записи в файле каждая на новой строке, то у вас неправильный разделитель целой и дробной части - в системе, видимо, установлена точка в качестве разделителя. в Delphi для контроля разделителя используется `DecimalSeparator` , как в pascalABC.net - не знаю (думаю, можно воспользоваться системными функциями), но всегда можно проверить строку и поменять запятую на точку. Кстати, это же касается и первого варианта.

Comment: Вообще-то, правильно не _поменять запятую на точку_, а передать в функцию конвертации строки в число правильные настройки форматирования (FormatSettings).

Comment: @kot-da-vinci, да, вы правы. К сожалению, справка по pascalABC.net весьма убога, и сам язык пока на уровне становления, хотя и обещает стать чем-то большим